How can I run a script upon raising the lid on my laptop?
I am running Kubuntu 24.10 on my ASUS ROG G733P laptop (Plasma version 6.1.5).  There doesn't seem to be a control to turn on the keyboard LED backlights in System Settings, but I can get them to work by using the shell command "sudo brightnessctl --device='asus::kbd_backlight' s 95".  This does the job for me.
Unfortunately, the keyboard lights to out every time I close the laptop lid, so when I open it, I have to retype the command.  This is a problem when I am in a dark room and can't see the keyboard well.
I would like to have this command run every time the laptop lid is opened, or alternatively, not have the lights go out when I close the lid.  I already have the optinon to do "nothing:" when the lid is closed in power management, but that doesn't keep the lights on.
So... how do I run a command when the laptop lid is raised, and how do I do it as root without having to open a shell?
Thanks!
